# Saving a Value from input to a Map with Visual Force

Tags: apex, visualforce, map

Simple question (or not). What would be the best way to save a value to a Map?

The Name is {!newPerson['key1']} <- this works

`<apex:inputField label="Name" value="{!newPerson['key1']}"/>` <- this doesn't work

I've only managed to bind values to lists but is there any way to do the same with a Map? This map is Map btw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure about the type of map that you're passing to the page. But in the `apex:inputField` you should bind the field and not the entire object. Hope the below code helps!

```
public class saveValuetoMap{

    public map<id, account> accountMap{get;set;}
    public set<id> keyList{get;set;}

    public saveValuetoMap(){
        accountMap = new map<id, account>([select id, name from account limit 10]);
        keyList = new set<id>();
        keyList = accountMap.keySet();
    }

}
```

VF pages:

```
<apex:page controller="saveValuetoMap">
  <apex:form>
      <apex:pageBlock>
          <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!keyList }" var="key">
              <apex:column headerValue="Account nAME">
                  <apex:inputField value="{!accountMap[key].Name}"/>
              </apex:column>
          </apex:pageBlockTable>
       </apex:pageBlock> 
   </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're map is an SObject, you'll need to follow @theGreatDanton's approach, since inputfield can use maps in the value as long as it returns a field, i.e. `value="{!objectMap[index].field_name__c}"`.

If your newPerson is just a map of strings you won't be able to use `inputField` since Visual Force has no way of telling what field it is, and hence the field type, and other metadata that controls how the field displays.  Instead you'll want to use `inputText` which doesn't require the additional field metadata to display.

Comment: I've changed Map<String,String> to Map<String,Object__c>, it works now, thanks!